# Text overflow beyond page bottom when compiling amsart document on HAL

Tags: compiling, amsart, overflow

I uploaded a `tex` file to [HAL](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/), compiled it via their submission form and noticed that the text continues beyond the bottom margin. I tracked the issue down to the `amsart` package. How do I fix this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Output: (page 1 of 1)

[image]

Comment: It works for me... The page is broken after the fifth line of the fifth paragraph;

Comment: Could it be an encoding issue?

Comment: what is HAL, can you give a link?

Comment: Sorry, https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/

Comment: I just tried it there and it worked. I really don't see how encoding would've done this... Also, HAL uses TeXLive 2016 (If I compile `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pdftexbanner
\end{document}` there it prints `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) kpathsea version 6.2.2`), so anything that works in TL'16 should work there too...

Comment: Thanks. It does seem to me that the issue was caused by the byte order mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new `.tex` file, copied the MWE to this file, and it compiles perfectly on HAL. The new file was encoded in ANSI. In emacs: `undecided-unix`.

The `.tex` file I was uploading also compiles badly when uploaded through another device. So something was wrong with that file itself. It was encoded in UTF-8, with BOM. In emacs: `utf-8-with-signature-dos`.
Interestingly, when I change the documentclass to `article` in that buggy file, on HAL the output pdf starts with a blank page. So the symptoms vary.